# ChakraUI Can't Hide Select Icon completely

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I have the following component

```
<Select
      style={{ paddingInlineEnd: "0px" }}>
      ...
    </Select>
```

Setting the **iconSize** property to 0px seems to successfully affect the HTML element with the class **chakra-select__icon**. However the wrapper class **chakra-select__icon-wrapper** remains unaffected. Because the icon retains **width** and **height**. How can I remove the icon completely from the page?

Setting the **icon** property to the following element has no effect

```
<span style={{height: "0px", width: "0px"}}></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by going to the library and finding a similar question: https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/discussions/3104

The end code looks like this:

```
const Select = {
  // parts: ["icon"],
  baseStyle: {
    icon: {
      height: "0px",
      width: "0px",
    },
  },
};

const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts,
  breakpoints,
  components: {
    Select,
  },
});
```